# Is it possible to use spread on multiple columns in tidyr similar to dcast?

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

I have the following dummy data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
dt <- expand.grid(Year = 1990:2014, Product=LETTERS[1:8], Country = paste0(LETTERS, "I")) %>%   select(Product, Country, Year)
dt$value <- rnorm(nrow(dt))
```

I pick two product-country combinations

```
sdt <- dt %>% filter((Product == "A" & Country == "AI") | (Product == "B" & Country =="EI"))
```

and I want to see the values side by side for each combination. I can do this with `dcast`:

```
sdt %>% dcast(Year ~ Product + Country)
```

Is it possible to do this with `spread` from the package **tidyr**?

Comment: @jaap this question is not duplicate of the older one. The older one is about reshaping data in general, this one is about how to achieve certain pivoting within the specific package.

Comment: This _**is**_ a dupe. It is true that the other question doens't focus on a specific question and therefore has attracted solutions with several packages, including the one asked for by you. This makes it a perfect target to close specific questions.

Comment: @Jaap I'd argue this is not a duplicate. This question is about creating the column names from multiple source columns, with a single column for values. Whereas the linked question is about picking values from multiple source columns, with one column used for names. Some answers to the linked question reshape the problem so that it can be solved with solutions to this question, but that doesn't make them duplicates.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

One option would be to create a new 'Prod_Count' by joining the 'Product' and 'Country' columns by `paste`, remove those columns with the `select` and reshape from 'long' to 'wide' using `spread` from `tidyr`.

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 sdt %>%
 mutate(Prod_Count=paste(Product, Country, sep="_")) %>%
 select(-Product, -Country)%>% 
 spread(Prod_Count, value)%>%
 head(2)
 #  Year      A_AI       B_EI
 #1 1990 0.7878674  0.2486044
 #2 1991 0.2343285 -1.1694878
```

Or we can avoid a couple of steps by using `unite` from `tidyr` (from @beetroot's comment) and reshape as before.

```
 sdt%>% 
 unite(Prod_Count, Product,Country) %>%
 spread(Prod_Count, value)%>% 
 head(2)
 #   Year      A_AI       B_EI
 # 1 1990 0.7878674  0.2486044
 # 2 1991 0.2343285 -1.1694878
```

Comment: Yeah, this was the first thing that came to my mind. But it is not pretty :)

Comment: @mpiktas. I can only think of this method.  May be somebody else will come up with compact code :)-

Comment: well there is `unite()` but it appears to only work with numeric data (on purpose though?).

Comment: @beetroot, thanks, Yes,  It seems to work `sdt%>% unite(Prod_Count, Product,Country) %>% spread(Prod_Count, value)%>% head()`

Comment: @akrun Ah yes great, I thought it's `c("Product", "Country")` and got an error message, my mistake then.

Comment: This is the Hadley approved way of solving this problem ;)

Comment: After having consulted this thread multiple times the last months, I find the reshape2/dcast-based solution the most elegant. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418919/dplyr-with-subgroup-join, where the spread-based solution cannot be generalized to multiple grouping columns, but the reshape-based can.

Comment: @DieterMenne Thanks for the input.  Yes, there are limitations in `spread`.  I would also say that the `dcast` method has also limitations with multiple `value` columns.  Heard that in the next release of `data.table`, it would be fixed.

Comment: @hadley this is an unusually ugly solution for the tidyverse. All the columns have to be listed out multiple times, and what's worse they lose types, so everything has to be cast back to numeric.

Answer (score 10):

With the new function `pivot_wider()` introduced in tidyr version 1.0.0, this can be accomplished with one function call.

`pivot_wider()` (counterpart: `pivot_longer()`) works similar to `spread()`.
However, it offers additional functionality such as using multiple key/name columns (and/or multiple value columns).
To this end, the argument `names_from`—that indicates from which column(s) the names of the new variables are taken—may take more than one column name (here `Product` and `Country`).

```r
library("tidyr")

sdt %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = Year,
                names_from = c(Product, Country)) %>% 
    head(2)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>     Year   A_AI    B_EI
#>    <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1  1990 -2.08  -0.113 
#>  2  1991 -1.02  -0.0546
```

See also: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
 # Concatenate grouping vector: 

dt$PC <- paste0(dt$Product, "_", dt$Country)

# Spread the vectors by year: 

dt2 <- reshape(dt[,c(!(names(dt) %in% c("Product", "Country")))],

               idvar = "Year",

               ids = unique(dt$Year),

               direction = "wide",

               timevar = "PC")

# Remove "value.", from the vector names:

names(dt2) <- gsub("value[.]", "", names(dt2))
```

Data:

```
dt <- expand.grid(Year = 1990:2014,

                  Product = LETTERS[1:8],

                  Country = paste0(LETTERS, "I"))

dt$value <- rnorm(nrow(dt))
```