# partially spread out tidy data by repeated measures

Tags: r, tidyr

I have some data structured like this:

```
structure(list(subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("group1", "group2"), class = "factor"), measurement = c("color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time", "color", "time"), item_pos = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4"), value = c("blue", "1508", "orange", "752", "black", "585", "red", "842", "red", "879", "white", "1455", "green", "1757", "orange", "2241", "white", "2251", "yellow", "1740", "red", "1962", "yellow", "1854", "green", "1859", "blue", "2156", "yellow", "2494", "green", "1757"), item = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D")), .Names = c("subject", "group", "measurement", "item_pos", "value", "item"), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which has multiple observations by subject by item, so the data for subject 1 looks like this:

```
> filter(df.tidy, subject==1)
  subject  group measurement item_pos  value item
1       1 group1       color        1   blue    A
2       1 group1        time        1   1508    A
3       1 group1       color        2 orange    B
4       1 group1        time        2    752    B
5       1 group1       color        3  black    B
6       1 group1        time        3    585    B
7       1 group1       color        4    red    A
8       1 group1        time        4    842    A
```

So within a `group` each `item` appears twice, and for each occurrence there is a  `measurement` of color and time. The order in which items appear is in `item_pos`.

While I like this long format, a colleague needs it slightly 'wider', with the repeated color and time measures in their own colums by item. The *desired format* would be as follows:

```
  subject  group item color1 color2 time1 time2
        1 group1    A   blue    red  1508   842
        1 group1    B orange  black   752   585
...
        4 group2    D yellow  green  2494  1757
```

My feeling is that this ought to be possible using a combination of `gather()`, `spread()` and other dplyr verbs, but I'm not sure what the dplyr equivalent here would be for (in for-loop speak) looping through the items by group and collecting the color and time observations in subsequent columns. Help much appreciated!

Related questions I consulted:

- [tidyr repeated measures multiple variables wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775461/tidyr-repeated-measures-multiple-variables-wide-format)
- [is it possible to use spread on multiple colums in tidyr similar do dcast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929954/is-it-possible-to-use-spread-on-multiple-columns-in-tidyr-similar-to-dcast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `dcast` from `library(data.table)`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df.tidy)`, grouped by 'subject', 'measurement' and 'item', create a sequence column "N" and then use `dcast` to convert from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df.tidy)[, N:=1:.N, by = .(subject, measurement, item)]
dcast(df.tidy, subject+group + item ~measurement + N, value.var="value", sep="")
#   subject  group item color1 color2 time1 time2
#1:       1 group1    A   blue    red  1508   842
#2:       1 group1    B orange  black   752   585
#3:       2 group1    A    red orange   879  2241
#4:       2 group1    B  white  green  1455  1757
#5:       3 group2    C  white yellow  2251  1740
#6:       3 group2    D    red yellow  1962  1854
#7:       4 group2    C  green   blue  1859  2156
#8:       4 group2    D yellow  green  2494  1757
```

---

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`, we group by the same column, create a sequence column ("N"), `ungroup`, paste the 'measurement' and 'N' columns to create 'measurementN' (using `unite`) and then `spread` the data to 'wide' format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df.tidy %>%
    group_by(subject, measurement, item) %>% 
    mutate(N = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    unite(measurementN, measurement, N, sep='') %>%
    select(-item_pos) %>% 
    spread(measurementN, value)
#  subject  group  item color1 color2 time1 time2
#    (int) (fctr) (chr)  (chr)  (chr) (chr) (chr)
#1       1 group1     A   blue    red  1508   842
#2       1 group1     B orange  black   752   585
#3       2 group1     A    red orange   879  2241
#4       2 group1     B  white  green  1455  1757
#5       3 group2     C  white yellow  2251  1740
#6       3 group2     D    red yellow  1962  1854
#7       4 group2     C  green   blue  1859  2156
#8       4 group2     D yellow  green  2494  1757
```

Comment: Lovely! Using `row_number()` on a grouped df to make a sequence column was the step I was missing.

Nice to have the data.table method as well. Not familiar with the `[, N:=1:.N, ...]` notation, how does that work exactly?

Comment: @strangeloop We  assign (`:=`) the sequence (`1:.N`) to a new column.for each combination of groups.  That is when there is new group, it starts the sequence again from 1 to the number of rows.